# Get elements with specific class and not a specific style

Tags: javascript

With plain JavaScript, how can I get all the elements who do not have a CSS style? I need to get the rows of a table which are not hidden, and they don't have an explicit 'display' attached.

```
<table>
<tr class='form-row-links'>
Stuff...
</tr>
</table>

document.querySelectorAll('.form-row-links[style="display:is_not_none;"]') //pseudocode, of course :)
```

The css style `display=none` is applied after the initialisation of the page, to the `<tr>` element.

Comment: How is the style applied, then? Can you post an example table so we can see what sort of thing you're working with?

Comment: [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: Do you have control over the adding of `display:none`? I mean, can you modify that code?

Comment: Yes; actually I found a much easier way of dealing with this: just initialise the <tr> with a declared display:table-row so that I can grab that. I'm not sure why I didn't think of that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Ry- for pointing me towards the [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

I actually thought that I could just declare an initial style of the row, which might then be overwritten by my JavaScript with 'none' or not:

```
<table>
<tr class='form-row-links' style='display:table-row;'>
Stuff...
</tr>
</table>

document.querySelectorAll('.form-row-links[style="display:table-row;"]')
```